# C# Change Decorator component with new

Tags: c#, pointers, decorator

```
public class Decorator : ICommonInterface
{
    ComponentType baseRef {get; set;}
    ComponentFunction //Function that i want to modify with the Decorator
    {
        //Additional stuff i want to do here
        baseRef.ComponentFunction() // do stuff
    }
}
public class DecoratedClass : ICommonInterface
{
    ComponentFunction(){ //do stuff }
}
```

This is pretty much how i'm defining my decorator. I'm using it like that:

```
main(){
    DecoratedClass _base = new DecoratedClass();
    Decorator _end = new Decorator(_base);
    _end.ComponentFunction() // I use the Decorator _end ComponentFunction instead of
                             // doing _base = new Decorator(_base) so i keep base reference
}
```

But at some point inside main, i'll have to do something like:

```
main(){
    // some point later inside main
    _base = new ClassThatInheritsFromDecoratedClass()
}
```

I'll still be using the _end variable to call ComponentFunction(), but _end has the old _base value. 
In C/C++ i could play with pointers and not use the **new** keyword to redefine _base or something, but is it possible to change _base like that in C# and _end.baseRef be the new value of _base without doing something like:

```
_end.baseRef = _base
```

after i change _base with the **new** keyword?

Comment: I oversimplified somethings to not have a really long text, but to explain just a bit more, there are two different sistems interacting with the component: One adds decorators to a component, other directly changes it in some way(some ways would be changing _base). So if _end kept the new value of base, like a pointer in C/C++ like i said, it wouldn't be necessary to write a complex mediator pattern for the sistems to interact with eachother. Also, it's for a game so those changes may happen at a random time in the game loop

Comment: Can you clarify why you cannot set `_end = new Decorator(_base)` after you changed `_base`?

Comment: The way things are implemented right now won't allow it. Like I said, those are two completely different systems that changes the component(_base) in a different way. One adds decorators to it and then use the decorators(_end is the last decorator on the stack) and other changes _base directly, permanently. If changing _base on this other system "updated" _end reference to _base, like i can with pointers and addresses in C/C++ it would make my life much more simple because it wouldn't be necessary to write a complex mediator class for those two systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a base object, then on top of that, you got decorator A and decorator B. So now you want to change the base value without re-decorate it with A and B.

One trick to to have a wrapper class like

```
public class DecoratedClassWrapper {
    public DecoratedClass RealBase { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the Main()

```
Main()
{
    DecoratedClassWrapper _base = new DecoratedClassWrapper();
    Decorator _end = new Decorator(_base);
    _end.ComponentFunction(); // I use the Decorator _end ComponentFunction instead of
                             // doing _base = new Decorator(_base) so i keep base reference
    _base.RealBase = new Something();
    _end.ComponentFunction(); // Now, this will executed with new "real" base.
}
```